# Matlab: using regexp to get a string that has a whitespace in between

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to use Regex to acquire some ID's in a cellstring array, the array looks like this:

```
myString = '(['US04650Y1001', 'US90274P3029', 'HON WI', 'US41165F1012'])';
```

My pattern for regex is as follows:

```
pattern = '[A-Za-z0-9.^_]+';
newArr = regexp(myString, pattern,'match');
```

I'd like to get the ID called 'HON WI', but with my current pattern, its splitting it into two because my pattern can't deal with the whitespace properly. I would like to get the whole "HON WI", as well as my other strings, everything that's in '', these might have special characters like ^, . or _, but I don't know how to add the whitespace.

I already tried stuff like this, without success:

```
pattern = '[A-Za-z0-9.^_\s]+';
```

My new array should have, in each cell, the strings/ID's contained in myString (US04650Y1001, US90274P3029, HON WI and US41165F1012) with dimensions 1x4.

Another approach that seems to work but not entirely sure:

```
myString = strrep(myString,'([','');
myString = strrep(myString,'])','');
myString = regexp(myString,',','split');
myString = strrep(myString,'''','');
```

This seems to get me what I want, but I would like to know how can I alter the regex on my first approach.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a mere `'([^']+)'` regex and use `'tokens'` to get the captures:

```
myString = '([''US04650Y1001'', ''US90274P3029'', ''HON WI'', ''US41165F1012''])';
pattern = '''([^'']+)''';
newArr = regexp(myString, pattern,'match', 'tokens');
```

The `newArr` will look like

```
{
  [1,1] = 'US04650Y1001'
  [1,2] = 'US90274P3029'
  [1,3] = 'HON WI'
  [1,4] = 'US41165F1012'
}
```

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. 
Would this work as well with special characters such as "^", ".", "-", and stuff like that? Some strings I work with have those special characters and my pattern covered it good. But I'm not sure if this one will.

Comment: @AquilesPáez `'[^']+'` matches a `'`, then captures 1 or more chars other than `'` into Group 1 and then a `'` is matched. So, you see that `[^']`, a negated character class, matches any chars you may imagine in between two single quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot again Wiktor. Regular expressions is truly a craft that takes time to be mastered.

Answer (score 1):

You may option is to use lookaround assertions. The following will match any string made of alphanumeric character or underscore (`\w`), space (' ') or characters `.` or `^`, that is located between quotes. This will specifically exclude the blank space next to the comma, in the separation between tokens, i.e. `', '` does not give a match.

Note that `\s` will match any blank space character (including tab, newline), this is why a space is preferred here:

```
pattern2='(?<='')[\w.^ ]+(?='')';

  pattern2 =
  (?<=')[\w.^ ]+(?=')

newArr = regexp(myString, pattern2,'match');
newArr'

  ans = 

      'US04650Y1001'
      'US90274P3029'
      'HON WI'
      'US41165F1012'
```